# How to load a flutter web app from Webflow?

Tags: flutter, url, webflow

I'm a flutter dev(switched to flutter from Native mobile apps), trying to build a full on website, so decided to build a hybrid of Flutter + Webflow - marketing home page in Webflow (because I've heard flutter web is not the best for SEO) and the core product pages in flutter.

When tapping on a link in the top menu on home page, it should open the web app built in flutter.
(there'll be a firebase authentication layer in between as well, and if it's an authenticated user, it can directly go to the flutter web app, without showing the home page).

I'm new to web development, so my knowledge in web is very limited. Looking for advice on how to implement it! Is it easy(or stupid)?